# JQuery - If statement for Eform

Tags: jquery, forms

i am trying to populate a text box based on the outcome of a dropdown.

currently if i use:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //if Department is changed
  $("#Field9").on('change',function(){
    $("#Field27").val(3);
});
```

i get "3" in the correct field so that's fine i know the field references are correct.

my scenario is i want to customise "Field27" based on the options in the dropdown ("Field9".

my existing code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //if Department is changed
  $("#Field9").on('change',function(){

  //check is equal to planning
   if($("#Field9").val() == "Planning"){
      $("#Field27").val(3);
   }
      else{
      $("#Field27").val(4);
     }

    }
});
});
```

can anyone advise why the if statement is not working as desired? it's not even populating 4 in the "else" statement

[image: Example here]

Comment: can you please provide your HTML which includes your fields?

Comment: last but 1 line, notice extra } so just remove it to );

Comment: If you were indenting your code correctly... It would have been obvious. -- Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Javascript is not Java...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, your code doesn't look so weird, except for indentations and an useless curly bracket.
I think you should use your browser's console mode and see some logs by putting "console.log()" functions.
Here is my example...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //if Department is changed
  $("#Field9").on('change',function(){
  //check the Field9's value in console.log()
  console.log($("#Field9").val())
  //check is equal to planning
  if($("#Field9").val() == "Planning"){
    $("#Field27").val(3);
  }else{
    $("#Field27").val(4); 
  }

  } <--unnecessary bracket? plz remove.
  });
});
```

Hope this would be helpful.

Comment: thank you so much knew it'd be an easy fix :) have a great day